# How to get the String value of a column name in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

The following SQL is trying to select some values, where it satisfies the condition that

```
select cd as key_type, decode
from general_code 
where key_type = 'A_MAP_TYPE'
and cd in (
    select distinct(A_MAP_TYPE)
    from sales_channel
);
```

`A_MAP_TYPE` is a column name (and FK) in table `sales_channel`, and it is being referenced in `general_code` (as PK).

I realize that this SQL is non portable in that when the name of `A_MAP_TYPE` changes, i.e. to `B_MAP_TYPE`, then the corresponding SQL needs to be changed. Is there a way to do something like `PL/SQL`'s `TABLE_NAME.COLUMN_NAME%TYPE` in this SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use dynamic SQL. It would probably require some changes to the way your query is setup now, but should be doable.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm

You basically would need to turn your current query into a string, and execute the string. Where your current A_Map_ field is, that would be a parameter. For the first case you would need to quote it so that it's still a string within the executing string. For the second A_Map_ field, you would put quotes around it,

Answer (score 2):

Not really.  You can build dynamic SQL and use execute immediate, but I wouldn't recommend that.

It's also possible to code generate it using the column metadata.  At this point it's like a dynamically generated CREATE VIEW or CREATE PROC - it's only done once and compiled into a database object.

You can have an exception process which inspects the metadata against data in the table to find things which may need to be updated.